# Dllimport/PInvoke binary compatibility

Tags: c#, c++, .net, .net-core, pinvoke

I'm learning about PInvoke to use a C++ library (with C-Style interface) in C#. After reading the documentation and searching Google/StackOverflow for additional information I was wondering about binary compatibility of the native library and .Net. I think I read something somewhere a while ago, but I couldn't find it anymore. And I could not find anything else on this.

When I compile a C/C++ to use in .Net, do I need to use certain configurations like compiler flags to make it compatible for PInvoke? Can I use native libraries made with different compilers in one .Net project, provided these libraries don't depend on each other?

I there anything else I need to know about C/C++ compilation for .Net PInvoke?

I would like to use GCC and CLang with CMake projects to create the native libraries.

Comment: P/Invoke has a lot of adaptation capabilities. However, it's not binary compatible with C/C++ ABI, but if a piece of C/C++ code can be used by P/Invoke, it's not dependent on the C/C++ compiler (MSVC or other). Or try to refine your question.

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for your reply. I can't refine the question because I don't have more details. I just couldn't find any docs, tutorials or posts at all that said whether there are or aren't any dependencies on the native libraries (except the C interface).

Comment: Note P/Invoke is also cross platform (with .NET Core): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke . Again, it does not mean it'll be able to use any C++ construct, but it will see all C++ compilers as equal citizens

Comment: Ok. If you put your comments into an answer I would mark this thread as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P/Invoke has a lot of adaptation capabilities. Also P/Invoke is [cross platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke) (with .NET Core).

However, it's not binary compatible with C/C++, but if a piece of C/C++ code can be used by P/Invoke, it's not dependent on the C/C++ compiler (MSVC or other), or said in another way, it will not be able to use any C++ construct, but it will see all C++ compilers as equal citizens